# Database listening with Laravel Websocket

Tags: laravel, database, websocket

I have done every installation related to Laravel Websocket. Here's what I'm trying to do: I have a table in the database where I keep my orders. When a new order arrives, I want to print it to the console on my home page blade.

I would be glad if you help. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Read https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting, and probably https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events to do so when a new order model is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use model event like below, in your Order model

```
protected static function booted()
{
    //everytime when new order is created this function will be called
    static::created(function ($order) {
        //then broadcast event
        NewOrder::dispatch($order);
    });
}
```

Then you have to define channel in youre route/channel.php

```
use App\Models\Order;

Broadcast::channel('newOrder', function ($user) {
   return $user->id;
});
```

Then create event `php artisan make:event NewOrder`

```
class NewOrder implements ShouldBroadcast
{

/**
 * The user that created the server.
 *
 * @var \App\Models\User
 */
public $user;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
 *
 * @return Channel|array
 */
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('newOrder');
}
}
```

then listen for NewOrder event in newOrder Channel

```
Echo.channel(`newOrder`)
.listen('NewOrder', (e) => {
    console.log(e.order);
});
```

Read Documentation more info https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting#pusher-channels